# How to make my angularjs + Django web application SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, django, angular.js

I'm working on a web application that will allow users to create a dedicated page for them like www.example.com/john.doe

So the structure I've come up with is this:

1. Landing Page: Pre-rendered at server with no Angularjs
2. Application: Built with AngularJs
3. User Pages: Pre-rendered at server with no Angularjs

Is this design correct and necessary if I want my landing page and the users' dedicated pages to be crawled?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from building the entire site in AngularJS. For tthe last few years Google has been able to analyse the javascript and CSS on a site to identify the more interactive elements and javascript generated content for crawling purposes. A number of sites these days are built entirely on top of AngularJS without the need to have various pages being entirely generated on the server side (including a very large highly ranking Australian business listings site very similar to what you are proposing). What you are proposing with a landing page and user pages being rendered server side will work but there is no requirement to do so and you could quite easily build the entire site with AngularJS without any greater SEO issues than you would encounter by having certain pages generated server side.